# Visual C++/CLI mutual access between two class objects?

Tags: visual-c++, class, namespaces, c++-cli

Here is the problem:

```
namespace Program1 {
   public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
   {
    public: Form1(void) {....}
         private: RunnableThread^ peerThread;

   private: System::Void loginButton_MouseDown(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e) {
    String^ ip = this->ipTextField->Text;
    String^ port = this->portTextField->Text;
        <.............>
        // Start new thread
        this->peerThread = gcnew RunnableThread("thread2", ip, port, this->gameMatrix, this);
        <..............>
    }
}

   }


// Runnable class
ref class RunnableThread
{
private:
    String^ ip;
    String^ port;
    <...>
    EchoClient3WS::Form1^ refToRootObj;
    <......>
public:
    RunnableThread(String^ threadName, String^ ip, String^ port, GameMatrix^ gameMatrix, Program1::Form1^ rootObj);
    void run();
    void callServer(String^ message);
    void done();
};
```

---

And I got error:

The line is:

```
'private: RunnableThread^ peerThread;'
```

Then error is:

> error C2146: syntax error : missing
>   ';' before identifier
>   'peerThread'  k:\visual studio
>   2010\projects\program1\program1\Form1.h
>   <....>

---

It seems, that

```
namespace Program1 { public ref class Form: <...> {   
// HERE WE DON'T KNOW ANYTHING ABOUT THE CLASS NAMED 'RunnableThread'

 } }
```

But I also can move the 'RunnableThread' declaration code before the 'namespace Program1', because the 'RunnableThread' uses pointer to father 'Form1' , who created an instance of this class.

How to solve this problem?

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: This silly headache is one of the reasons so many C++/CLI programmers have switched to C#.  Recommended, winforms programming in C++/CLI has no advantages and no future.

Answer (score 1):

Add a forward declaration before `class Form1`:

```
class RunnableThread;
```

probably with the `ref` in front.